# Microsoft.Solutions.ResourceSelector - latest aure portal SDK doesn't recognize options->filter - is the Example out of date?

Tags: user-interface, azureportal, azure-managed-app

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/microsoft-solutions-resourceselector

IS this example out of date?

"c:\Users\idani\Desktop\POC----\src\Default\Extension\Extension.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(CompileDxExtension target) ->
c:\Users\idani\Desktop\POC----\src\Default\Extension\Client\Create\CreateRedisForm.dx.json(35,41): error JSON0101: Failed to valida
te the schema of JSON file 'c:\Users\idani\Desktop\POC----\src\Default\Extension\Client\Create\CreateRedisForm.dx.json'. Details: Pro
perty 'filter' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties. [c:\Users\idani\Desktop\POC----\src\Default
Extension\Extension.csproj]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: literally the example from the docs does not compile using SDK 8.305.0.5